Is there a way to make iCloud downloads sync?
I have two macs, and I've been going back and forth between them working on a project that I'm storing on my desktop. I seem to have made something unhappy, and now my laptop isn't updating from the cloud.
I've logged into icloud.com and confirmed that the updates were sent from the desktop, they're just not propagating back down to the laptop.
Is there anyway to force it to happen? There's no little "cloud" icon to click on.

On the laptop, I created a new file in the working directory. For about a minute it displayed "waiting to upload" and then all of a sudden everything synced.
